# Node.js - JSON in a textbox compiled to var

Tags: json, node.js

If I had a JavaScript object like so as text in a textbox on a webpage:

```
{
firstName:'olegzandr',
lastName:'denman',
fullName: function () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

how could I take the JSON from the textbox and turn it into a variable in my server-side node program?

Comment: the problem I am having is that there is no <input type="textarea">, only <input type="text">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a person object that knows how to construct an instance from the serialized form and how to be serialized.

```
function Person (details) {
  this.firstName = details.firstName;
  this.lastName = details.lastName;
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

Person.prototype.toJSON = function () {
  return {
    firstName: this.firstName,
    lastName: this.lastName
  };
};
```

Comment: JSON.parse should be all you need to do. My problem is that I can't capture the text from a <textarea> html element. In other words, if I submit a form with <textarea> element in the form, I can't get the text, really strange problem to have, this should be easier.

Comment: the problem is there is no <input type="textarea">